# How to access the color property of an HTML link object in the DOM

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a page with various links and I would like to be able to determine which links were visited/not visited by users accessing the page.
My first attempt was using the following code

```
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("link_id")).getPropertyValue("color");
```

This code didn't do the job because it did not differentiate between visited/not visited links:
in both cases the output was the same color.

My second vector was to use to use the CSS "visited" selector - i.e. setting the same property (for example background-color) to all visited links and then use a javascript for loop to append all links with the chosen background-color to some list).

My assumption is that if the browser sets different colors to the links there must be some way to access the updated value of the color property in the DOM.

what am I doing wrong? any ideas?

Comment: sniffing the visited pseudo is a kind of tricky since the webpage-author would gain the ability to see what pages the user visited. afair there were several discussion because of privacy and stuff. have a look on this article: https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/

Answer (score -1):

To access the color css property from javascript you can use the `style` property of the DOM element

```
document.getElementById("link_id").style.color
```

But, if you need to tailor the style of your anchors based on whether the link has been visited or not, simply use the `:visited` pseudo class to style the anchors...

```
a:visited
{
    color:Maroon;
}
```

Here's a [Working JS Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/Ut4sQ/) that should override the browser's default, if it doesn't in your own project, then you might be inheriting some styles and need to force an override with `!important`...

```
a:visited
{
    color:Maroon !important;
}
```

Comment: This just accesses the `color` property as set (if set) in a `style` attribute on the element. It has nothing to do with visiting links.

Comment: True, didn't read the whole question and got carried away by the title